# initialize subdictionary of subdictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, initialization

I initialise a dictionary of about 100 keys; Some keys are initialised as subdicts using dictionary comprehensions; One key in particular has eight subdicts as values, one of which is anomalous to the other seven & I would like guidance as to the best way to handle this.

This is one key & how I'm initialising it:

```
d = {...,
     ...,
    "activity": {
        k: {int(v): 0 for v in range(0, 24)}
        for k in (
            "rts_all",
            "rts_thirty_days",
            "years",
            "seven_days",
            "thirty_days",
            "ninety_days",
            "all",
        )
        },
        ...,
}
```

But, the key "activity" also needs a further key with a subdict as a value:

```
"weekdays" = {
    k: 0 for k in ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
}
```

At the moment, I'm initialising the whole of the rest of the dictionary and then finally doing the following:

```
d["activity"]["weekdays"] = {
    k: 0 for k in ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
}
```

This works fine, and is reasonably clear, but also seems a bit *ad hoc* to me.

Is there a neater mechanism?
Am I missing something terribly obvious?
Am I overthinking?

Comment: What is the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: Okay I thought of an optimization and answered it below! Check if it helps you! @coderedacted ?

Answer (score 0):

One optimization is using [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) which will create a dict with all values of 0

```
dct = dict.fromkeys(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], 0)
print(dct)
#{'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 0, 'Wed': 0, 'Thu': 0, 'Fri': 0, 'Sat': 0, 'Sun': 0}
```

```
d['activity'].update({'weekdays':dct})
```

Another change is to use `dict.update` to update your dictionary